# Posting information via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to navigate through pages and state a variable 's' between them with a value, I usually do it "name.php?s=p" for example, but I thought there is a way to:

```
www.myweb.com/?s=p
```

For example.

I need to get the value inside the `?s=` and read whats in it.

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
console.log($(location).attr('s'));
```

Is it possible with jquery?

Comment: `location` isn't a DOM element. It cannot be inflated into a jQuery object and it does not have attributes.

Comment: Didn't know what their called Quentin so didn't see that ^_^

Comment: I used what you stated Quentin regex is good (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl plugin and write below code. In your case you want to search for "s" then below code should work.

```
 $.url().param('s');
```

Comment: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: see updated ans its a plugin @Quentin

Comment: please remove downvote or give any other reason of downvote @Quentin

Comment: he has given the reason then I have modified my answer but still there was downvote that is why I asked for the reason @BoltClock I am not pushing anything

Answer (score 0):

You can send the variable with a Post Action between page and another, instead of GET method, if you are using the Rewrite mode.